# $W_2(f,0) = \frac{1}{2} \# f^{-1}(l)$?

Tags: differential-topology

There must be some rather straight forward reason for $W_2(f,0) = \frac{1}{2} \# f^{-1}(l)$ but I really get stuck with why. Could someone help me out?

[image]

Comment: What is $W_2(f, 0)$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I believe it's the winding number of $f$ about $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the proof of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem preceding this theorem. (Starting on page 91 of Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology*)

Guillemin and Pollack show that
$$W_2(f,0) \equiv \tfrac{1}{2}\# f^{-1}(l) \pmod 2$$
in their proof of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem. But the conclusion of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem says that for a function
$$f: S^k \longrightarrow \Bbb R^{k+1} \setminus \{0\}$$
such that
$$f(-x) = -f(x) \text{ for all } x \in S^k,$$
we have that
$$W_2(f,0) = 1.$$
Hence $f^{-1}(l)$ cannot be empty for any line $l$ through the origin of $\Bbb R^{k+1}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much Henry!